# Correct way of generating unique id for iOS device even after app reinstall using keychain

Tags: ios, swift

After reading various links and q's on SO, i am creating unique id and saving it in keychain.

The requirement is to persist the unique id across app reinstalls. But I want to prevent syncing this value to iCloud to prevent issues when user backs up to different devices.

This is how i am creating unique id in **Swift**:

```
let kcWrapper = KeychainWrapper() 
let uuidObject = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
let uniqueStr = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidObject)
kcWrapper.mySetObject(uniqueStr, forKey:kSecValueData)
kcWrapper.writeToKeychain()
```

The wrapper i am using is from this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password

Does this sync unique id to cloud or do i have to explicitly set it not to sync?

Comment: You may want to look at `identifierForVendor` in the `UIDevice` class

Comment: I checked it and it will vary once if user uninstalls all apps from a developer and reinstalles the app again. I need across reinstall

Comment: you may need to use _keychain_ and _iCloud_ as well; that could pretty much helps carry on the unique identifier between devices for a certain user during your application's lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need to prevent synchronisation to iCloud. But if you want some info be available only on current device (like your unique identifier) then you can use correct keychain item accessibility attribute `kSecAttrAccessible`. One with suffix "ThisDeviceOnly", see the list of possible constants to use: https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1658642-keychain_services/1663541-keychain_item_accessibility_cons.

From iOS 8 `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked` used by default so you need to set ThisDeviceOnly mode explicitly to restrict synch to other devices.

Update:
For github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess keychain wrapper you need to specify needed accessibility attribute when initialising it:

```
let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.example.github-token")
    .label("github.com (kishikawakatsumi)")
    .synchronizable(true)
    .accessibility(.whenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly)
```

then this accessibly attribute will be added to stored items.

Comment: thanks for the link. But i am using a different keychain wrapper. I don't have to specify accessibility attribute when saving a value. Here is the link for the library: https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess

Comment: @kishorer747 I checked wrapper which you mentioned - it definitely support specific accessibility attributes. See the public enum Accessibility. For example you can use next initialisation code: let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.example.github-token")
    .label("github.com (kishikawakatsumi)")
    .synchronizable(true)
    .accessibility(.whenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly)